# segfault while finding sames in Same Game using QT-C++

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn QT and while learning I wanted to develop a Same Game.
I have a subclass of QGraphicsItem which is Gem
and a subclass of QGraphicsScene whics is GameScene.

I connected clickedOnMe signal of each Gem in the scene to the clicked slot of GameScene.
Signal provides a pointer to the clicked object. And GameScene class holds a list of pointers to the Gem's in it.

So far i have tried only finding end deleting the sames, no replacement of any gem. When I run the game and click on a gem it sometimes works well and deletes all same gems and sometimes it gives segmentation fault. I couldn't understand where my problem is.

```
void GameScreen::clicked(Gem *cGem){

// cGem is the clicked gem

if(cGem)
{
 //find cGem in the list and erase from list
    QList<Gem*>::Iterator i = gems->begin();
    for(; i != gems->end(); ++i)
    {
        if(*(*i) == *cGem)
        {
            gems->erase(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // end of erasing
QList<Gem*> neighbours;
    for(i=gems->begin(); i != gems->end(); ++i)
    {
        if((*i) && (*i)->doesItTouch(cGem) && (*i)->getColor() == cGem->getColor())
            neighbours.append(*i);
    }

    delete cGem;

    while(!neighbours.isEmpty())
    {
        clicked(neighbours.first());
        neighbours.removeFirst();
    }

}

return;
```

}

and here is the Gem::doesItTouch(Gem *oGem)

```
if(oGem)
    return (qAbs(x - oGem->getX()) + qAbs(y - oGem->getY())) <= 1;
return false;
```

Comment: This looks fishy:
        clicked(neighbours.first());
        neighbours.removeFirst();

Comment: Can you give the stack trace from the core dump file?

Comment: @dvai I'm a newbie in programming and I don't know how to do what you said.

Comment: @uLtRaLoVeR : You could use a loop using find_if, i.e. while((fit=find_if(gems->begin(),gems->end,predicate))!=gems->end()) erase(fit); // the predicate compares the objects pointed to with *cGem, i.e. not the pointers because they need to be dereferenced.

Comment: Dieter Lücking: Perhaps if clicked() removes an element from neighbours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a situation where you have a gem (`x`), that has a neighbour on the right side of it (`a`) and underneath it (`b`).

```
--xa--
--bc--
```

Now when it goes through the `neighbours` list, lets say it passes the neighbour on the right side of it (`a`) to the `clicked` function. Now if this gem has a neighbor underneath it (`c`), it will pass that to the `clicked` function. And now you're in a situation where the gem on the left side (`b`) of this gem is the same gem that is below the first gem (`x`). This will delete that gem, but it will still be in the `neighbours` list of the first gem (`x`), which is an invalid pointer and it will pass it to the `clicked` function which will try to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to add or remove to or from a container while iterating over it. It invalidates the iterator. All kind of things can happen.

Comment: Can you give some advice?

Comment: It's also leaking `Gem` instances. Is it needed to manage them by pointer?

Comment: Check out QMutableListIterator Class